# Buying English edition of iWork in France

Tags: macos, iwork

I live in France and have just bought a MacBook Pro. I want to by the boxed edition of iWork.  But they only sell the French version, and as I do not speak the language and am English, I want the English version.  Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to buy the apps from the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 5):

iWork has **multi language support**. If you buy iWork in a French packaging, you can still use a different language on your Mac.

The language used in any iWork program will be the same as in your System Preferences set in OS X.

#### Advantages of the Mac App Store version

- There is no disadvantage (besides no install DVD) when buying the iWork suite from the Mac App Store. You can download it again and again, because the purchase is linked to your ID.
- You can also install it on *up to ten computers* if they are linked to your Apple ID. The iWork with packaging may only be installed on one computer (single licence) or up to five (family licence).
- You don't have to buy the whole iWork suite at once in the Mac App Store. E.g. It's up to you to only buy keynote, if that's all you need.

#### Supported Languages

English, Chinese, Danish, Dutch, Finnish, French, German, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Russian, Spanish, Swedish

Answer (score 0):

You can buy it on [Amazon.co.uk](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_6?url=search-alias=software&field-keywords=iwork%2011&sprefix=iwork%20,aps,165#/ref=sr_kk_2?rh=i%3asoftware,k%3aiwork%2011%20for%20mac&keywords=iwork%2011%20for%20mac&ie=UTF8&qid=1329432958)

Comment: Can you please provide a link to it? Thanks!